# Custom exceptions in python starlette

Tags: python-3.x, api, exception, starlette

I am trying to raise the custom exception using the starlette framework in python. I have the API call which checks some condtions depends on the result, it should raise exception.
I have two files app.py and error.py

````
#app.py
        from starlette.applications import Starlette
        from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
        from starlette.routing import Route

        from error import EmptyParamError

        async def homepage(request):

          a=1
          b=0

          if a == 1:
             raise EmptyParamError(400, "status_code")

         return JSONResponse({'hello': 'world'})


        routes = [
           Route("/", endpoint=homepage)
        ]

       app = Starlette(routes=routes,debug=True)`

#error.py ```
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

class BaseError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status_code: int, detail: str = None) -> None:
        if detail is None:
          detail = "http.HTTPStatus(status_code).phrase"
       self.status_code = status_code
       self.detail = detail

    async def not_found(self):
       return JSONResponse(content=self.title, status_code=self.status_code)



 class EmptyParamError(BaseError):
         """ Error is raised when group name is not provided. """
        status_code = 400
        title = "Missing Group Name"
````

When the condition is true, i want to raise the exception but its not returning the jsonrespnse but its returning the stacktrace on the console.
Please let me know if anything is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

adding try block resolved the issue

```
   try:
        if a==1:
            raise InvalidUsage(100,"invalid this one")

        if b == 0:
            raise EmptyParamError("this is empty paramuvi")
    except InvalidUsage as e:
        return JSONResponse({'hello': str(e.message)})
    except EmptyParamError as e:
        return JSONResponse({'hello': str(e.message)})
```